# Inspect docker container FS changes from host

Tags: docker, unionfs

I've started a docker container and I've modified a file. At some point later I'd like to inspect this change from the docker host. Now I use `docker cp` to export the file, inspect it, delete it. But this multistep copy-read-delete process seems like over kill if I just want to read a file.

Is there a better way to inspect filesystem changes in a docker container?

I need more info than `docker diff` is showing.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the filesystem of a running container the Docker data directory, usually `/var/lib/docker/`. The specific location varies depending on which [storage driver](http://blog.docker.io/2013/11/docker-0-7-docker-now-runs-on-any-linux-distribution/) is used. In the case of AUFS, the location is `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/${CONTAINER_ID}/.

```
$ HELLO_WORLD=$(docker run -d  ubuntu:12.04 /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo Hello world; sleep 1; done")
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2524e196adf0        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/sh -c while tru   4 seconds ago       Up 3     seconds                            naughty_brown
$ echo $HELLO_WORLD
2524e196adf0b985e84a22503d5fd1f2110c6a0cf175f12496f11f0043e799fa
$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/${HELLO_WORLD}/
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general solution, but in special cases, you can use mounted volumes:

Start the container with volume:

```
sudo docker run -v /host_path/shared:/shared <container>
```

Store files you want to inspect in container dir `/shared` or copy & ln files to `/shared` and make needed files symbolic links to files stored in `/shared`.

```
cp /mydir/myfile /shared/myfile
ln -s -f /shared/myfile /mydir/myfile
```

Then you can inspect these files directly in `/host_path/shared`.

Note: You cannot symbolic-link special files like `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/hostname` etc.